# Importing ES6 module using SystemJS with Babel is giving errors

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, systemjs

I am new to [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) and it is giving me a hard time, for example, it shows an error when I import the following module

```
const labels = [{
 name: "l1",
 title: "Title"
}];
export default labels;
```

however if i write `exports["default"] = labels;` instead of `export default labels`, it shows no error and returns an object named **r** with labels in default key.

My SystemJS config is like

```
System.config({
    baseURL: "/",
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    transpiler: "babel",
    babelOptions: {
      "optional": [
        "runtime",
        "optimisation.modules.system"
      ],
      "stage": 1,
      "blacklist": []
    },
    map: {
      babel: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js"
    }
  });
```

And I import the module like

```
  System.import("config/labels").then(function (a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
  });
```

The libraries I am using are

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.23/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.23/system.js"></script>
```

Please help me in configuring the SystemJS properly, and tell me why is it giving such errors.

Comment: I haven't tried to use this system js setup, but I can tell you that looks like babel 5 configuration options and you are loading babel 6.